# adding tables dynamicly in spring via jdbctemplate

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

In springJdbctemplate crud application I want to give user an option to create a new custom table with custom fields.The problem is if I create query to create table ,how can I give the user the option to customise it ,as domain class are fixed.Some one suggest to dump data in xml.

thanks

Comment: Can you explain better your goal? It's unclear which are your needs. Provide example of what have you tried or what you want to realize

Comment: In springJdbctemplate crud application I want to give user an option to create a new table with custom fields.The problem is if I create query to create table ,how can I give the user the option to customise it ,as domain class are fixed.Some one suggest to dump data in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have user table metadata definition in this way:
**Domain classes** (pseudo-code):

```
class UserTableMetadata {
  String tableName;
  // List of personalisable columns
  List<UserTableColumnMetadata> columns;
  // List of personalisable indexes
  List<UserTableIndexMetadata> indexes;
}

class UserTableColumnMetadata {
  // Owner table
  UserTableMetadata table;
  String columnName;
  int jdbcType;
  int lenght;
  int precision;
  boolean nullable;
}

class UserTableIndexMetadata {
  // Owner table
  UserTableMetadata table;
  String indexName;
  boolean unique;
  boolean primary;
  // Index columns
  List<UserTableColumnMetadata> columns;
}
```

As you can see domain classes are fixed, but you can build up a simple table definition with Name, Columns and Indexes.
After that can be easy - processing metadata - build the `create table` SQL code in dynamic way (or `alter table` if user change column definition and table already exists).
Metadata can be stored in database as well as on XML, it's only a choice based on your preference and requirements.
Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.Do I have to create domain class for every table manually or can it be done automatically.

Comment: Do you mean for every user table? If yes you can't create domain class  manually but have to use Javassist (for example); you domain classes are tables metadata I wrote above and you have to manage all dynamically. This is all I can say, I givbe you a good advice, the rest must be coded by you, using your capabilities and knowledge (and learn how to resolve problems step-by-step). Resolve this question is a funny work, enjoy it! :)